# How to write docker private registry reverse proxy via golang?

Tags: docker, go, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy in golang for my private registry, however the following snippet has unexpected behavior:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)
    http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:9090", nil)
}

func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf(r.URL.Path + "\n")
    remote, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:10000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

I used `docker run -d -p 10000:5000 -v docker_image:/var/lib/registry\ registry` to run a private docker registry container.

After running the code, I used `curl 127.0.0.1:9090/v2/_catalog` and I got the correct answer, but when I used `docker push 127.0.0.1:9090/hello-world:latest` (after running `docker tag`), the docker client threw `Get "http://127.0.0.1:9090/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused`.

I checked the logs and it seems that my code does not even get the `http` request.

What could I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hello, I tried the example above unmodified and it worked for me just fine. Are you sure you are using the correct port , the image is tagged properly and that the proxy is still running?

Comment: Hi, I'm changing localhost to real ip 10.*.*.* and it works fine for me, but I'm still confused why localhost dose not work for me.

Comment: This is clearly something very specific to the system/environment you have (i used the same image, ports, code). Check what localhost resolves to and if it resolves to 127.0.0.1, whether 127.0.0.1 works (I assume it doesn't from the initial description of the problem). Check the listening ports in your system.

Comment: Generally, `Get "http://127.0.0.1:9090/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused` means that your system was not happy about this connection and it is very common to happen with the host is not expecting connections on the port.

Comment: You are not using a remote docker daemon, are you? Like in a VM or something? Then its localhost is different from curl's on your host.

Comment: actually I did not use a remote docker, using `curl 127.0.0.1:9090/v2/_catalog` I can successfully get the image name, That's why it confused me.